# Unsure how to find out whether the Child process is terminated via completion or a signal

Tags: c, signals, sigint

I'm trying to write a program where,

- My parent process should be able to ignore the SIGINT signal and
- My child process, on the other hand, should perform the default function of the SIGINT signal.
- And finally, I should find out whether the Child process was terminated by any particular signal.
- My child process basically executes an execvp(), based on some input.

Hence, the way I went about trying to do the same is, I added a SIGINT handler for my parent process and my guess is when the execvp() function is invoked, the child process would perform the SIGINT process using the default handlers.

```
 void sigint_handler(int signum){
    printf("");
 }

int main(int argc, char **argv){

pid_t pid = fork();

if(pid<0)
{
printf("fork: error");
exit(-1);

}
else if(pid>0){
    int status;
    signal(SIGINT,sigint_handler);
    pid_t child_pid= waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
    printf("");
}
else if(pid==0){
    printf("");
    if(execvp(argv[1],&argv[1]) == -1) {
    printf(" ");
    exit(-1);
      }

}

}
```

Is this code sufficient to handle the same? Also, if my child process is terminated by SIGINT or SIGSEGV etc, how would I go about finding whether my child process was terminated after completion or because of a signal and what signal was used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value from `wait()` or friends for the status tells you — use the macros `WIFEXITED()` and `WIFEXITSTATUS()` for ordinary exit, or `WIFSIGNALED()` and `WIFTERMSIG()` for signal (the `IF` macros test how it exited, of course).  There are also `WIFSTOPPED()`, `WIFCONTINUED()` and `WSTOPSIG()` for job control.

See POSIX [`waitpid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html) (which documents `wait()` too).  And most Unix-based systems also provide a `WCOREDUMP()` too, but POSIX does not mandate it.  You can also look at the exit status in hex (4 digits) and it does not take long to spot the patterns, but you should use the macros.

---

> For the first part of my question, would my above-mentioned code ignore the `SIGINT` signal while it is still in the parent part of the process?

Beware: [avoid using printf() in signal handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891019/how-to-avoid-using-printf-in-a-signal-handler).

It wasn't clear how your signal handling code was working; you'd chopped too much code from the question.  However, you've now added enough of the missing code, and, as I guessed, your code isn't bullet proof because the `signal()` call shown is after the `fork()` and in the parent process. You should disable the signal before calling `fork()`; then the child should re-enable it. That protects the processes properly.

For example (file `sig11.c` — compiled to create `sig11` using `gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes sig11.c -o sig11`):

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s command [arg ...]\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    bool handle_signals = (signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN) != SIG_IGN);

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "fork: error\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else if (pid > 0)
    {
        int status;
        pid_t child_pid = waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
        printf("child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", (int)child_pid, status);
    }
    else
    {
        assert(pid == 0);
        if (handle_signals)
            signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
        execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to exec %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(-1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
$ ./sig11 sleep 40
^Cchild 19721 exited with status 0x0002
$
```

We can debate whether you should be using [`sigaction()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html) rather than [`signal()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/signal.html) another day.

The check for `handle_signals` means that if the program is run with SIGINT ignored, it does not suddenly enable the signal.  This is a standard defensive technique.  Note that errors are reported on standard error, not standard output.  There's no need to check the return value from `execvp()`; it doesn't return if it is successful and if it does return it definitively failed.  It would be possible to report a better error using `errno` and `strerror()`, but what's shown is not wholly unreasonable.  The check for enough arguments is another defensive measure; reporting the correct usage is good manners.  I also converted the `if` / `else if` / `else if` into `if` / `else if` / `else` + assertion — the third test is unnecessary.

---

Using the macros from `<sys/wait.h>`:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s command [arg ...]\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    bool handle_signals = (signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN) != SIG_IGN);

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "fork: error\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else if (pid > 0)
    {
        int status;
        int corpse = waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
        printf("child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);
        if (WIFEXITED(status))
            printf("child %d exited normally with exit status %d\n", corpse, WEXITSTATUS(status));
        else if (WIFSIGNALED(status))
            printf("child %d exited because of signal %d\n", corpse, WTERMSIG(status));
        else
            printf("child %d neither exited normally nor because of a signal\n", corpse);
    }
    else
    {
        assert(pid == 0);
        if (handle_signals)
            signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
        execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to exec %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(-1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Example outputs:

```
$ ./sig11 sleep 4
child 19839 exited with status 0x0000
child 19839 exited normally with exit status 0
$ ./sig11 sleep 10
^Cchild 19842 exited with status 0x0002
child 19842 exited because of signal 2
$
```

Comment: Thanks! Also, for the first part of my question, would my above-mentioned code ignore the SIGINT signal while it is still in the parent part of the process?

Comment: Beware: [avoid using `printf()` in signal handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891019/how-to-avoid-using-printf-in-a-signal-handler).  It isn't clear how your signal handling code is working; you've chopped too much code from the question.  Your code isn't bullet proof, though, if the `signal()` call shown is after the `fork()` and in the parent process.  You should disable the signal before calling `fork()`; then the child should re-enable it.  That protects the processes properly.

Comment: The printf in the simply to check whether the handler was working and I updated the code in my answer